# 2 way notification on queue

Tags: java, queue

I have a typical producer consumer problem, the only difference is that the consumer doesn't have to work on each unit of the producer produces. The the producer is done with a fixed amount of data then the consumer should take it. In addition the producer should wait until the consumer has read the batch.

I am using TransferQueue for this, but now i want that after a fixed time i should read the data even if the size is small.

typically i needs a 2 way notification of the queue, how can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to use two Threads.

The idea is that the producer will put new data into your `Queue` until the desired number of entries are there. Then it waits (`wait()`) for notification (`notify()`).
On the other hand the consumer will also wait till the right ammount of data is in the queue OR till the defined timeout is reached (`wait(int timeToWait)`). Then it will process the data and notify the Producer to work on.

Comment: Actually i am doing something on these lines only here is a snippet of the code.  Thread 1:    `synchronized (unprocessedData) {
                if (thresholdReached()) {
                    unprocessedData.notify();
                    unprocessedData.wait();
                } else 
                    unprocessedData.add(data);
        }`  Thread 2:    `synchronized (unprocessedData) {
 unprocessedData.wait(10 * 60 * 60);    
 //Do something
 unprocessedData.notifyAll();
}`  I was hoping for something more refined.

Answer (score 0):

Worked on a similar problem where I need to determine the end of data from producer to commit a batch and start next. I used instanceof to determine the end of objects.

Basically, created EndOfData class and send this object as last entry into the queue. The consumer checked whether the object received was instanceOf data class or EndOfData.

Introduces additional if check but worked well for me. Hope that helps.